# Can I configure SSMS intellisense to sort correctly?

Tags: sql-server, sorting, intellisense, sql-server-2008

There are two tables that I am working with that have similar names: `Projections` and `ProjectionStatus`.

If I type `select * from projections`, intellisense autocompletes the table name to `ProjectionStatus`. I have to arrow down to `Projections` or delete the incorrectly autocompleted table name to get the query I want.

Is there a way to configure intellisense to sort the list alphabetically?

Changing the names of the tables isn't an option. (`projections` and `projection_status` would prevent the issue, obviously)

Comment: I believe IntelliSense uses the most-recently-used methodology for sorting.  I doubt there is an easy option to change that.

Comment: No, you cannot change how IntelliSense sorts, sorry.

Comment: @AaronBertrand Would have made a perfectly valid answer worthy many, many lucky charms.

Comment: @MaxVernon: If I run the query, `projections` is the most recently used, but if I type the query again, intellisense stil auto-completes with the wrong table.

Comment: @AarolamaBluenk I had it as an answer, then deleted it. Feels more like a comment.

Comment: @AaronBertrand: no, because in that case if I typed `projections`, intellisense wouldn't autocomplete the wrong table.

Comment: @AaronBertrand: What IDE do you use for SQL Server? I'd love to find a better option than SSMS and don't mind paying for it.

Comment: @HeadofCatering I use SSMS. I don't use most of the wizards (they're often not flexible enough), and I never use any of the visual designers (much prefer reliable DDL and DML), but otherwise it meets all of my needs. I actually don't know of any appropriate replacements or what features you are looking for that SSMS doesn't have. The 2012 version of SSMS is much better. If you are unhappy only with IntelliSense, you can always use try out [Red-Gate's SQL Prompt](http://www.red-gate.com/products/sql-development/sql-prompt/) (though I don't know this specific issue will work better there).

Comment: Thanks. I'm probably going to adopt your approach and stick with SSMS.

Answer (score 0):

It typically sorts itself alphabetically by default, why don't you try clearing your cache? That seems to solve 99% of intellisense issues.

In SSMS, Edit > Intellisense > Refresh Local Cache

Or just, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd> .

Comment: SSMS sorts alphabetically in most cases, but it doesn't follow the rules we all learned in grade school for shorter versions of longer words. Intellisense thinks `projections` should be sorted after `projectionstatus`.

Comment: You are right, in that case it's how it is, I agree there is no way to change the order.  I can't help but wonder if there's a way to edit what's in that cache, but I doubt it's worth it.